# Using 3D Warehouse models in Blender (Sketchup - Collada - Import)

Tags: import, file-format, collada, outliner, compatibility

There is an incredible wealth of 3D models available on Google's 3D Warehouse. Unfortunately these models come in Sketchup format. I have read a lot of tutorials on this, and everybody seems to praise Blender's Collada integration. 
However, I still get very mixed results when using Collada export to transfer the models:

- pieces are missing
- objects are combinations of hundreds of meshes, spread randomly throughout the outliner, grouped in non-logical groups
- scaling is almost always wrong
- when going into edit mode, the triangulation is all wrong so no UV unwrap possible (I have read on this forum that this is inherent to the ways Sketchup works)
- materials are never exported in the right way
- I have tried every possible combination of the Sketchup export options but no success so far when using .dae

My question: Is this because not all 3D warehouse models are made by professionals? Am I doing something wrong? Is there something superior to Collada to export (via Autodesk files?) I thought that inter program compatibility was the whole point of Collada...

Thanks very much.
Some examples below:

[image: Very simple mesh object imported, this is the Outliner view]
[image: Missing components, weird empties and dotted lines]

Comment: Sketchup doesn't create clean geometry. There is a lot of rebuilding and cleaning that goes into using Sketchup models in Blender. Are the problems that you are having due to Collada or Sketchup...that is the question.

Comment: I really don't know. However I don't see any other way to use the 3D Warehouse models in Blender.